# Fetch values in deeper nodes in Firebase Database

Tags: json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I get data in the nodes in the nodes like "01_01_2017_01_00_AM" which are dynamic and even there are multiple children with auto generated push IDs. I need to process results matching the current date in the above format and then display.

By the way I am working with Firebase and Cloud Functions.

[Database preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDUAf.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can only query one level at a time in Firebase.

You could do a query like this if you know the `mail_data` key.

```
admin.database().ref('mail_data/e...IG2')
.orderByKey()
.equal to('01_01_2017_01_00_AM')
.once('value')
.then(snapshot => { ... });
```

Which would get you the snapshot of your object.